# What is the relationship between Java EE and WebLogic?

Tags: java, php, zend-framework, codeigniter

I know this is a stupid question. But I really have very limited knowledge in programming. I've experience writing PHP code back in school, and I know that there is a framework called codeigniter, which includes very basic functions and libraries used for facilitating PHP programming.

Is Java EE to Java and WebLogic like codeigniter to PHP and some php-based web application (e.g., a forum)? I mean, is Java EE a framework or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Java EE is not a framework. It is a seperate edition of java for Web development process. for deploy(run) web application we need a server. Weblogic is one of the server.

Comment: Amith, IMHO that's not entirely correct. WebLogic among others -is- Java EE; it's *a* implementation of it. Although "framework" is not always consistently used, I do think that Java EE qualifies as a framework. Java EE also had a broader scope than just web development.

Answer (score 0):

Java EE is a standard. According to [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html)

> Java Platform, Enterprise Edition (Java EE) 6 is the industry standard for enterprise Java computing. Utilize the new, lightweight Java EE 6 Web Profile to create next-generation web applications, and the full power of the Java EE 6 platform for enterprise applications. Developers will benefit from productivity improvements with more annotations, more POJOs, simplified packaging, and less XML configuration.

WebSphere Application Server, JBoss Application Server and other are implementations of the above mentioned standards.

Google really helps a lot, please look into it before posting :)

Comment: Thanks. I know Google helps, and I really like Googling before I paste any question here. But sometimes, it just happened that the more you google, the more you are confused. :P That's when I come here to ask you geeks. :) According to your post, am I correct to say that J2EE is like an IDE and a framework combined? I think an analogy would help a lot here. I am trying to find one to connect the problem to something I've learned or know... :)

Comment: JEE (J2EE is renamed JEE) is not an IDE, it's a standard with specifications for building enterprise applications. Here is JEE 6 [specifications](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316). Eclipse, NetBeans are some of the IDEs. WebLogic Application Server and others are built according to the specifications to be JEE compliant. The specifications make the applications portable from WebLogic to WebSphere to JBOSS and others in theory.